# Filtering serializer response data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ManyToMany relation with tag and items:

```
class Tag(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # ToDo Change max length
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class Item(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fav_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')
```

I need all fields to be serialized, but i wish to only limit the response values. 
Example:

What I'm receiving now:

```
{
    "user": 2,
    "image": null,
    "title": "test3",
    "message": "testmessage",
    "fav_count": 0,
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "tag1",
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "tag2",
            "description": null
        }
    ]
}
```

But i only wish to receive the tag ids not the name and description...

My simple view:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Would i need to rebuild my response data to include/exclude or is there a better way to do this? (or if iv missed the terminology)

Comment: show you `ItemSerializer` plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` DRF field in your serializer

Example

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('tags', 'image',.....other fields)
```

Response

```
{
    'image': 'image1',
    ...........
    'tags': [
        89,
        90,
        91,
        ...
    ]
    ..........
}
```

In you want to do it dynamically based on a request parameter.

```
   class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        tags = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_tags(self, obj):
       if self.request.get('some_condition'):
           data_tags = TagSerializer(obj.tags, many=True).data
           data = map(data.pop('field_to_remove') for data in data_tags)
           return list(data)
       else:
           return TagSerializer(obj.tags, many=True).data
```

Then, pass request to your serializer when you init it in your view.

```
serializer = ItemSerializer(data, context={'request':self.request})
```

Comment: The first solution solves the problem. And i can see myself using the second one very soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probaply using serializer for `Tag` model and declare it in `ItemSerializer` so view is showing full `TagSerializer` info.
If you want to show only `pk` field, just use default representation, don't declare special serializer for `Tag` in `ItemSerializer`